# Interpolating data above the maximum value in a panel with R

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a panel with missing values that I need to interpolate.

```
a <- data.frame(id= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), year=1:7, index=c(1,NA,NA,NA,3,NA,NA, 2,NA,NA,NA,5,NA,NA))
```

The issue is that I don't have the final value, so I would like to use the same interpolation line to predict values above the last observation reported. Additionally, the interpolation should be "by id", rather than considering the first observation of the next id as part of the line.

I've tried the basic interpolation but it does stop at the latest values, or predicts using the next id:

```
a <- na.approx(a)
```

output I get:

```
       id year    index
 [1,]  1    1 1.000000
 [2,]  1    2 1.500000
 [3,]  1    3 2.000000
 [4,]  1    4 2.500000
 [5,]  1    5 3.000000
 [6,]  1    6 2.666667
 [7,]  1    7 2.333333
 [8,]  2    1 2.000000
 [9,]  2    2 2.750000
[10,]  2    3 3.500000
[11,]  2    4 4.250000
[12,]  2    5 5.000000
[13,]  2    6       NA
[14,]  2    7       NA
```

desired output:

```
        id year    index
 [1,]  1    1 1.000000
 [2,]  1    2 1.500000
 [3,]  1    3 2.000000
 [4,]  1    4 2.500000
 [5,]  1    5 3.000000
 [6,]  1    6 3.500000
 [7,]  1    7 4.000000
 [8,]  2    1 2.000000
 [9,]  2    2 2.750000
[10,]  2    3 3.500000
[11,]  2    4 4.250000
[12,]  2    5 5.000000
[13,]  2    6 5.750000
[14,]  2    7 6.500000
```

Comment: I'm not sure that was clear, but with "same interpolation line" I meant I would like to keep predicting NA assuming the slope to be the same after the last observed point

Comment: i get this error:
  0 (non-NA) cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `lm` you can get the slope that this simple interpolation is using, and then use that slope to generate new values with `predict`. But maybe there's a simpler solution

```
mod <- lm(index ~ year, a)

a[,2] <- predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(year=a$year))
```

### EDIT 1

No, for each `id` we will run a different lm. To do that we select the part of `a` with a unique `id` inside a loop, and run the lm only with that part:

```
for(i in unique(a$id)){
  ai = a[a$id==i,]
  mod = lm(index ~ year, ai)
  a[a$id==i,3] = predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(year=ai$year))}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was not general enough in my question. I edited it, sorry

Comment: Ok this is smart. I think it should work but I get this error now:   0 (non-NA) cases

Comment: But it does work nonetheless, so that's good! thanks!

Comment: My guess is that this error can happen if an `id` is full of NA's, so you can't run a regression without observations. To help you with how to work that out i'd need more info on the context of what you're doing. You could just accept that error, and ignore that specific id, or use the mean of the intercepts and slopes for the other `id`'s for example, but  that's arbitrary. You're welcome!

Comment: That's fine, I'll drop those ids. On a different note: I tried putting the predict function inside a ceiling() one to get only integer predictions but it's giving me weird results (always increasing even if the slope is flat). Any idea why?

Comment: By "flat slope" you mean slope coef. = 0? If yes then I don't know why is that happening... Maybe try `trunc` or `round` to see if the problem remains.

Comment: Yes, I meant coef=0, actually using round() solved it. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following data which is modified from the question in light of the comments, we define a function which returns NA if all `index` values are NA and `na.spline` otherwise and then apply it per id:

```
library(zoo)

a <- data.frame(id= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), year=1:7, 
  index=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 2,NA,NA,NA,5,NA,NA))

na_spline <- function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA else na.spline(x)
transform(a, index = ave(index, id, FUN = na_spline))
##    id year index
## 1   1    1    NA
## 2   1    2    NA
## 3   1    3    NA
## 4   1    4    NA
## 5   1    5    NA
## 6   1    6    NA
## 7   1    7    NA
## 8   2    1  2.00
## 9   2    2  2.75
## 10  2    3  3.50
## 11  2    4  4.25
## 12  2    5  5.00
## 13  2    6  5.75
## 14  2    7  6.50
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not general enough in my first post, I edited it

Comment: It's weird, I keep getting this error: Error in splinefun(x[!na], y[!na], ...) : zero non-NA points

Comment: maybe the error comes from ids for which all values of index are missing. while @ricardo's answer goes around that by getting the error only for the "empty" ids while computing the remaining ones where at least 2 values of "index" are there

Comment: I'm sorry i meant there might be ids for which all values of index are missing. I had not realized that

Comment: Your answer is more cleaner than ricardo's one, but looping through ids he solves the missing index problem. thanks a lot anyway

Comment: As I said in 2 previous comments, I don't have any missing ids, I have ids for which all values of index are missing. I really appreciate your help but please read carefully my comments so you don't have to update answers for no reason

Comment: that's a good solution. thank you and sorry for the confusion

Comment: Have revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
a %>% mutate(index = replace_na(index, 0)) %>% 
      mutate(index = accumulate(index, ~ .5 + .x))
  year index
1    1   1.0
2    2   1.5
3    3   2.0
4    4   2.5
5    5   3.0
6    6   3.5
7    7   4.0
>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not general enough in my first post, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the values follow a linear pattern. You could then use `fit=lm(index~year, data=a)` and then predict the values using `a$index=fit$coef[2]*a$year+fit$coef[1]`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not general enough in my first post, I edited it