# Apply na.approx on row and output dataframe in R

Tags: r, apply, interpolation, na.approx

Given the following dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Company = c('A','B','C','D','E'), `X1980` = c(NA, 5, 3, 8, 13),
                                `X1981` = c(20, NA, 23, 11, 29),
                                `X1982` = c(NA, 32, NA, 41, 42),
                                `X1983` = c(45, 47, 53, 58, NA))
```

I would like to replace the NA's with values through interpolation over the rows resulting in the following data frame:

```
Company  1980  1981  1982  1983
   A      NA    20   32,5   45
   B      5    18,5   32    47
   C      3     23    38    53
   D      8     11    41    58
   E      13    29    42    NA
```

I tried using na.apporox in combination with apply:

```
df1[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, FUN = na.approx))
```

But this results in the following error:

```
Fehler in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  Fehler bei der Auswertung des Argumentes 'x' bei der Methodenauswahl für Funktion 't': dim(X) muss positive Länge haben
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

EDIT:
I forgot to define how to treat the NA's in the na.approx function.

```
df1[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, na.approx, na.rm=FALSE))
```

This results in the desired output!

Comment: Read about the `na.rm` argument in `?approx`

Comment: Thanks markus! I overlooked that part in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This interpolation methods, from what i know, don't deal with `NA`'s at the end of the sequence, which is the case of entry Ex1983. So, `na.approx` (at least the one from `zoo` package) gives an optional argument `na.rm` for you to select if you want to remove those NA's or not.

By default it is `TRUE`, so it removes, giving your matrix a 4th column that only has 3 elements, not 4 (as the rest of the columns), so it produces that error. To deal with that you simply set that argument to `FALSE`:

```
df1[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, FUN = zoo::na.approx, na.rm=FALSE))
```

Output:

```
> df1
  Company X1980 X1981 X1982 X1983
1       A    NA    20    NA    45
2       B     5    NA    32    47
3       C     3    23    NA    53
4       D     8    11    41    58
5       E    13    29    42    NA
```

To fill that NA, i can help you use the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716694/interpolating-data-above-the-maximum-value-in-a-panel-with-r/64716852#64716852), if you need me to.